# How to create a loop to plug in elements of an array into a single line of code C#

Tags: c#, loops

Is it possible to create a loop to plug in array elements all in one line?
I want to be able to insert the elements "toBananas[0], toBananas[1]" into the var result, but suppose I don't know how many elements I need to insert overall. The amount of [elements] could range from [1] up to [99]. Is there a way to make it so the amount of elements lists out to the amount of elements I have without having to write each element into the result individually?

```
var result = await svc.GetBananas(input, "Food", new string[] { toBananas[0], toBananas[1], ... toBananas[99] });
```

Comment: What type is `toBananas`?

Comment: an element of an array. A string

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When you hover over toBananas in Visual Studio, what type does it tell you?

Comment: (local variable) string[]

Comment: So if it's already a string[], and you're trying to pass every element to GetBananas, then have you tried simply `var result = await svc.GetBananas(input, "Food", toBananas);` ?

Comment: Instead of creating a `new string[] { ... }`, why not just pass `toBananas` the element into the svc.GetBananas service call? If it's already a string array, there's no reason to create a new one.

Comment: sir, you fixed it and just made my code a lot simpler. can't believe i wasted so much time on something that simple. thanks ;D

Comment: One other thing you might want to read up on is the `params` keyword.  You can declare a function `void ProcessFoodNames(params string[] foodNames)` and call it like `ProcessFoodNames("Apple", "Artichoke", "Pork")` (any number of strings) and the body of the function will see an array of strings.  You can also pass it an array of strings (like your `toBananas`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.Linq Select to apply a function to each element in an IEnumerable.

```
toBanas.Select(toBanaa =>svc.Getbanaas(input,"food",toBanaa ))
```